# Finding the indices of the list of tuples based on comparison

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, comparison

I got a list of tuples. I want to find the indices in the list where the second element of the tuple is less than any of the first elements of the other elements. All the tuples in the list have the property that the second element is larger than the first element. This is my current code. But it is very inefficient as it has two for loops.

```
b = [(12.4967,12.6328), (2.7100, 13.5921), (2.3388, 12.0418), (0.9856, 13.8039), (5.2956, 12.2421), (3.9076, 13.0671), (6.3806, 11.6), (3.7320, 12.1615), (10.6809, 14.3437)]

c = set()
for t in range(len(b)):
    for a in b:
        if b[t][1] <= a[0]:
            c.add(t)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should be able to find the maximum value first (since you only need to compare to the highest since the second element is bigger) and get all the elements that are less than it.

```py
cutoff = max(x[0] for x in b)

c = set()
for i, x in enumerate(b):
    if x[1] <= cutoff:
        c.add(i)
```

Comment: shorted alternative: `c = {i for i, x  in enumerate(b) if x[1]<cutoff}`